# how can I decrease the number of exception fetcher status in apache nutch?

Tags: exception, hadoop, cluster-computing, fetch, nutch

I clustered apache Nutch with hadoop but I am not very familiar with either of them. In fetch part, when I look at FetcherStatus, I found the number of the exception quite alot(one thrid of the urls).My question is how I can decrease the amount of exception and increase the number of success urls...

and one more question I wonder  what happens to  exception urls in apache nutch. Are exception urls ignored in next crawls or they will be still used?

Any links, answers and comments are much appreciated

Comment: What is the exact exception that thrown during the fetch process? Does it timeout exception? Protocol exception? what is that?

Comment: I don't know what the kind of the exception is and how I can find it`s kind? but I know it happens during fetch process and map/reduce administration, shows the infos below  FetcherStatus : exception  3,066

Comment: Would you please check the hadoop.log file to see what is the thrown exception?

Comment: I don't know how to hadoop.log. How can I find hadoop.log? I have a logs folder in $HADOOPHOME that has a lot of  datas like below:               hadoop-hduser-datanode-satra-machine-master.log.2015-05-05  13227893 bytes  May 5, 2015 11:59:02 PM
hadoop-hduser-datanode-satra-machine-master.log.2015-05-06  10386275 bytes  May 6, 2015 5:39:28 PM

Comment: You have to look at your log4j.properties file in order to find out where the Nutch log file stored.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the conf/regex-urlfilter.txt file. In this file you can define which you'd like to include and exclude with regular expressions. By default some things are excluded, like URLs which contain a question mark or URLs ending with media formats.

Any URL that does not match the patterns you defined will not be stored in the DB, therefore will not be used in the next cycle.